# Displaying last column of ASP DataGrid( not gridview) in next line

Tags: asp.net, html, datagrid

I am using a datagrid in which I want to display my last column in next line or row and the next row in grid will shift down.

Name  Age  Sex  Subject

---

Mac   24  M   English, Science Maths, Geography

Nan   29  F   English, Science Maths, Geography

I want to display like this:

Name       Age      Sex

---

Mac         24       M
            English, Science Maths, Geography

Nan         29       F
            English, Science Maths, Geography

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

If you are not married to a DataGrid then I would recommend looking into the repeater control or the ListView control. It will give you a lot more freedom and be much easier to understand later

If for some reason you have to use a DataGrid there this a way, but it is very very hacky, it will be much harder to under stand when you look at this in a week or two, and is not a good idea in general but it achieves your goal.

```
   <asp:DataGrid ID="dg" ShowHeader="false" runat="server"
    AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundColumn DataField="Name"></asp:BoundColumn>
        <asp:BoundColumn DataField="Age"></asp:BoundColumn>
        <asp:TemplateColumn>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%# Eval("Sex") %></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3">
                 <%# Eval("Courses") %>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateColumn>
    </Columns>
</asp:DataGrid>
```

in the last column you are displaying the value for that column, then closing the td and tr that the control created. Then you are creating a new tr and td with a colspan equal to the number of columns and putting in the course values then letting the control close those trs and tds.

I strongly urge you to use a repeater or listview for this. It will make your life a lot easier.

Comment: I tried this way but I am not able to hide the last column header. If I hide the last column in datagrid then it hides the text of the last column which is there in next row. If I remove the HeaderText for last column, still it displays the empty column on the right which looks ugly. Also, if there is no data in the last column, it still displays the empty row.

Comment: If you have an extra column being displayed then you have to many columns created. you want n-1 columns. If you don't want headers to be displayed set ShowHeader to false on the DataGrid. updated code to not show headers

Comment: The repeater control suggestion is likely the best option here as it gives you full control over your output. This allows you to get the optimal desired results.